# Issues getting WPS working on ESP32

Tags: esp32, wifi

I am trying to implement [WPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup) on ESP32. [A WT32-SC01 Plus](http://www.wireless-tag.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/WT32-SC01-Plus-V1.3-EN.pdf) to be exact.
It seems to working so far that I'll get the WPS connection but then it takes around 5 minutes [!!!] to get IP address from the router.
Also when the WPS connection was successful, after a reboot it do not reconnect but expects a new WPS initialization.

Can you take a look and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "esp_wps.h"

#define ESP_MANUFACTURER  "ESPRESSIF"
#define ESP_MODEL_NUMBER  "ESP32"
#define ESP_MODEL_NAME    "ESPRESSIF IOT"
#define ESP_DEVICE_NAME   "ESP STATION"

struct WiFiHandler
{
    bool connected = false;
    bool connecting = true;
    bool wpsDone = false;

    WiFiHandler()
    {
        WiFi.mode( WIFI_STA );
        // WiFi.setAutoReconnect( false );
        WiFi.onEvent( [ = ] ( WiFiEvent_t event, arduino_event_info_t info ) -> void
        {
            switch( event ) {
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_START:
                    Output::Message( "Station Mode Started" );
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_PIN:
                    Output::Message( "PIN: %d", info.wps_er_pin.pin_code );
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_GOT_IP:
                    Output::StartUpMsg( "Connected" );
                    connected = true;
                    connecting = false;
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_DISCONNECTED:
                    Output::Message( "Reconnecting" );
                    WiFi.reconnect();
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_SUCCESS:
                    Output::StartUpMsg( "WPS Successfull." );
                    WiFi.disconnect();
                    wpsStop();
                    WiFi.begin();
                    wpsDone = true;
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_FAILED:
                    Output::StartUpMsg( "WPS Failed!" );
                    connecting = false;
                break;
                case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_TIMEOUT:
                    Output::StartUpMsg( "WPS Timedout!" );
                    connecting = false;
                break;
            }
        } );
    }

    bool initialise()
    {        
        int cnt = 0;
        TaskHandle_t taskHandle = NULL;
        xTaskCreate( this->blink, "WiFiConnect", 1000, this, 1, &taskHandle );        
        Output::StartUpMsg( "Establishing network connection ..." );
        
        if( String( WiFi.SSID().c_str() ).length() ) {            
            WiFi.begin( WiFi.SSID().c_str(), WiFi.psk().c_str() );
            while( ( WiFi.reconnect() != ESP_OK && !this->connected ) && ( ++cnt < 20 ) ) {
                lv_bar_set_value( ui_BootProgress, lv_bar_get_value( ui_BootProgress ) + 1, LV_ANIM_ON );
                delay( 100 );            
            }
        }
        if( !this->connected ) {
            WiFi.begin();
            Output::StartUpMsg( "Please initialise WPS connection on the router." );
            cnt = 0;
            if( wpsInit() ) {
                if( esp_wifi_wps_start( 1000 ) != ESP_OK ) {
                    Output::StartUpMsg( "Can't start WPS" );
                }
                while( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED )
                {
                    delay( 1000 );
                    if( WiFi.status() == WL_IDLE_STATUS && wpsDone ) {
                        WiFi.reconnect();
                    }
                    // if( WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTION_LOST && wpsDone ) {
                    //     WiFi.disconnect();
                    //     WiFi.begin( WiFi.SSID().c_str(), WiFi.psk().c_str() );
                    // }
                    Output::Message( WiFi.SSID().c_str() );
                    Output::Message( WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str() );
                    Output::Message( String( WiFi.status() ).c_str() );
                }
                delay( 2000 );
                this->connected = true;
            }
        }
        if( this->connected ) {
            while ( !WiFi.SSID().length() )
            {
                lv_bar_set_value( ui_BootProgress, lv_bar_get_value( ui_BootProgress ) + 1, LV_ANIM_ON );
                delay( 100 );
            }
            Output::StartUpMsg( "Connected to: " + WiFi.SSID() );
            while ( !String( WiFi.localIP() ).length() || WiFi.localIP().toString() == "0.0.0.0" )
            {
                lv_bar_set_value( ui_BootProgress, lv_bar_get_value( ui_BootProgress ) + 1, LV_ANIM_ON );
                delay( 100 );
            }
            Output::StartUpMsg( "IP: " + String( WiFi.localIP().toString() ) );
            delay( 500 );
            this->connecting = false;
            this->connected = true;            
        }
        return this->connected;
    }
    
    String getIP()
    {
        return String( WiFi.localIP().toString() );
    }

    String getPass()
    {
        return String( WiFi.psk().c_str() );
    }

    String getNetworkName()
    {
        return String( WiFi.SSID() );
    }

    String getMAC()
    {
        return String( WiFi.macAddress() );
    }

    static void blink( void *pvParameter )
    {
        WiFiHandler *l_pThis = ( WiFiHandler * ) pvParameter;
        for( int i = 0; l_pThis->connecting; i++ )  {
            i%2 ? lv_obj_add_flag( ui_WiFiStatus1, LV_OBJ_FLAG_HIDDEN ) : lv_obj_clear_flag( ui_WiFiStatus1, LV_OBJ_FLAG_HIDDEN ); 
            delay( 250 );
        }
        l_pThis->connected ? lv_obj_clear_flag( ui_WiFiStatus1, LV_OBJ_FLAG_HIDDEN ) : lv_obj_add_flag( ui_WiFiStatus1, LV_OBJ_FLAG_HIDDEN );
        vTaskDelete( NULL );
    }

    static bool wpsInit()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        esp_wps_config_t config;
        config.wps_type = WPS_TYPE_PBC;
        strcpy( config.factory_info.manufacturer, ESP_MANUFACTURER );
        strcpy( config.factory_info.model_number, ESP_MODEL_NUMBER );
        strcpy( config.factory_info.model_name, ESP_MODEL_NAME );
        strcpy( config.factory_info.device_name, ESP_DEVICE_NAME );   
        esp_err_t status = esp_wifi_wps_enable( &config );

        if( status != ESP_OK ) {
            Output::StartUpMsg( "WPS config failed! " + String( esp_err_to_name( status ) ) );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void wpsStop()
    {
        if( esp_wifi_wps_disable() ) {
            Output::StartUpMsg( "WPS Disable Failed" );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok people, my router was apparently acting weird. It seems to works fine now!

EDIT: Why the hell someone downvoted my answer? people are weird

Comment: how could anyone other than you solve the problem? it is not an Answer.

Comment: Nobody because it was a router issue. But as I posted it I assumed it was something with my code.